# What is the easiest way to pack and publish an npm module?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've been researching about this topic, many things I read are overlapping with babel, webpack, rollup, and even browserify. 
What's the standard way (or most common way) to easily publish source code written in es6 that can be consumed in browser with the script tag and in node with require? 
Equally confusing is how many versions are actually needed? I read that there are three - umd, cjs and original source, but isn't umd covering cjs already? And then I also see there's an es version(folder), which I think is identical to the source, why is that needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a library that supposes to run in the browser & in Node, you have several options:

1. Bundle it to [UMD](http://bob.yexley.net/umd-javascript-that-runs-anywhere/) with rollup (it creates smaller bundles then Webpack, especially recommended for bundling libs).
   This solution is the simplest one for you. The downside of it is if your lib allows partial imports (such as lodash allows to import only one function) then your consumers won't be able to do that, they will get your entire bundle.
2. Publish compiled files as esm + cjs when in package.json you point `main` field to `cjs` entry file & `module` field to the `esm` entry, in that why your lib consumers will able to import selectively parts of your lib.
   The benefit of that option is that your consumers will be able to apply several optimizations to your code, such as [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), module concat etc...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why the esm version? How is that different from the src? And doesn't UMD already cover cjs? That's why it's called "universal."

Comment: ESM - ecma script modules, the import / export syntax.
You are right UMD covers cjs.

Comment: ES6(with import export) is what I'm using to write the source, so why compile another version that is the same? That's my main confusion.

Comment: Its all a metter of how you want your consumers to consume your lib, if you publish a bundle, they won't be able to break it apart, if you want you consumers to bundle your code, and by that allow them optimize the imports, publish es6, modules, if your consumers are gonna use your lib in a browser, bundle your lib.

Comment: I asked a very specific question, why need the esm conversion when the source code is already in es6, what's the difference between this "esm" version you mentioned and the es6 source version?

Comment: @felixmosh answered your question there. It is a question of how you expect *other* developers to consume your library/package. The UMD and CJS options cover those who aren't strictly using ES6 and bundling their code, while the ESM version is for those who generally are, and gives them the ability to selectively include the components from your package that they *need*, rather than the entire package.